# unit Tests for Matlab Level2 / c- sfunctions

Tags: unit-testing, matlab, simulink

I am searching for a way to run tests on Matlab/Simulink sfunctions. For "normal" functions the xUnit-Framework is fine.

Is there any known approach to create tests for Level2 or c-sfunctions?

I know this will be much more complicated than a normal unit-test, but somehow this should be possible?

Is there any detailed information which parameters are needed to call an sfunction?

(I asked the question--got no answers--one Week ago on [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/56350-writing-tests-for-sfunctions))

Answer (score 0):

You can generate C code from your model, with appropriate **TLC** file (Target Language Compiler) that can inline the simulink s-function block in generated code.

Later you can perform testing on the generated code.

Also you can simulate the models if the s-function is properly written and provide test inputs/data to the model/s-function block at run-time.